# How can I find the derivative of an equation that includes a sum term?

Tags: functions, derivatives

I'm wondering how I can find the derivative of an equation that includes a sum term. I have the following equation:

$$ J(t) = \sum_{x=1}^{N} (k_x - ts_x)^2 $$

where $N$ = number of rounds (and the number of rounds is not provided).

I only have experience with solving simple derivatives, so now that the sum term has been included I'm not sure where to start (especially since I don't know how many items would be summed in total). I am trying to find the derivative:

$$ \frac{dJ(t)}{dt} $$

so that I can sketch the shapes of $J(t)$ and $\frac{dJ(t)}{dt}$ as functions of $t$. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is $N$ a function of $t$?  If not then $\frac {dJ}{dt}(t)=\sum_{x=1}^N 2(-s_x)(k_x-ts_x)$.

Comment: Derivative of a sum is the sum of the derivatives: $\frac{d}{dx}\sum f(x) = \sum \frac{d}{dx} f(x)$.

Comment: Do you know how to differentiate $x^2+2x+3$ (a finite sum)? If so, what is different about this sum?

Comment: Is there a reason you used so many >s?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)